# web scraping in python only retrieving one entry

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrap the BBC football results website to get teams, shots, goals, cards and incidents.

I writing the script in Python and using the Beautiful soup package. The code provided only retrieves the first entry of the table in incidents. When the incidents table is printed to screen, the full table will all the data is there.

The table I am scraping from is stored in incidents:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/result/partial/EFBO815155?teamview=false'
inner_page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soupb = BeautifulSoup(inner_page, 'lxml')    

              for incidents in soupb.find_all('table', class_="incidents-table"):
               print incidents.prettify()
               home_inc_tag = incidents.find('td', class_='incident-player-home')
               home_inc = home_inc_tag and ''.join(home_inc_tag.stripped_strings)


               type_inc_tag = incidents.find('td', 'span', class_='incident-type goal')
               type_inc = type_inc_tag and ''.join(type_inc_tag.stripped_strings)

               time_inc_tag = incidents.find('td', class_='incident-time')
               time_inc = time_inc_tag and ''.join(time_inc_tag.stripped_strings)

               away_inc_tag = incidents.find('td', class_='incident-player-away')
               away_inc = away_inc_tag and ''.join(away_inc_tag.stripped_strings)

               print home_inc, time_inc, type_inc, away_inc
```

I am just focusing one one match at the moment to get this correct (EFBO815155) before i add a regular expression into the URL to get all matches details.

So, the `incidents` for loop is not getting all the data, just the first entry in the table.

Thanks in advance, I am new to stack overflow, if anything is wrong with this post, formatting etc please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you please reduce the amount of code to the minimum amount that explains your problem? [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get the incidents table:

```
  incidentsTable = soupb.find_all('table', class_='incidents-table')[0]
```

Then loop through all 'tr' tags within that table.

```
  for incidents in incidentsTable.find_all('tr'):
           # your code as it is
           print incidents.prettify()
           home_inc_tag = incidents.find('td', class_='incident-player-home')
           home_inc = home_inc_tag and ''.join(home_inc_tag.stripped_strings)
           .
           .
           .
```

Gives Output:

```
Bradford Park Avenue 1-2 Boston United
None None
 2' Goal J.Rollins
 36' None C.Piergianni
N.Turner 42' None 
 50' Goal D.Southwell
C.King 60' Goal
```

This is close to what you want. Hope this helps!